# Coldfusion - How do I escape a variable inside of a variable?

Tags: variables, coldfusion

I'm making a survey of sorts and for one part I loop through all the questions, cfquery and then use the query as a variable. It looks something like this:

```
<cfloop index="q_number" from="1" to "10">

<cfquery name="q#q_number#_check" datasource="datasource">
  SELECT *
  FROM table
</cfquery>

<cfif len(#q#q_number#check.something#) GT 0>
```

I get an error because of the variable inside of the variable. Is there a quick hack around this?
I tried doing

```
<cfset escape_var = q#q_number#_check.question>
<cfif len(#variables.escape_var#) GT 0>
```

but that didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> ## q#q_number#check.something

The query is placed in the variables scope which means you can use array notation to access it. This works in CF9. Though you may need to add a [rowNumber] for CF8.

```
 <cfif len(variables["q#q_number#_check"].something) GT 0>
```

But you really should avoid querying within a loop. If you could elaborate on the requirements, we could suggest some better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif len(q#q_number#check.something) GT 0>
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Is the IF inside your look? if that is the case there is no need to have your query dynamically named.

If you need it out side of the look I would recommend sticking the results set in an array.

```
<cfset checkArray = arrayNew()>
<cfloop index="q_number" from="1" to "10">

<cfquery name="q_check" datasource="datasource">
  SELECT *
  FROM table
</cfquery>

<cfif len(q_check.something) GT 0>

</cfif>
<cfset arrayAppend(checkArray,qcheck)>
 </cfloop>
 <cfif len(checkArray[1].something) GT 0>

 </cfif>
```

You may have to play around with the IF statement to get the results your looking for but that should get you headed down the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use evaluate to save the query to a variable and then use it like you normally would.

```
<cfset resolved_query = evaluate("q#q_number#_check")>
<cfif len(resolved_query.something) GT 0>
```

Comment: True, but evaluate is overkill. Just use the variables scope.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting anything special within the loop, then why have the query there at all?
Could you not just use a single query. if you are using a where clause then use a query of queries inside your loop to get the other information.

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="ds">
select * from mytable
</cfquery>

<cfset myquestions = arrayNew(1)>

<cfloop index="q_number" from="1" to "10">

 <cfquery name="myotherquery" dbtype="query">
  select * from myquery
  where question = #q_number#
 </cfquery>


 <cfif myotherquery.something GT 0>
  <cfset myquestions[q_number] = myotherquery.something>
 </cfif>
```

Unless you need the results of the query inside your loop somewhere outside of the loop, you dont need a dynamic query name. Each time through the loop, the name will be overwritten.

I would just setup an array to store my loop results then i can use them later without the need to have 10 identical queries.

Hope that helps some
Tim